# laravel-8 storage accessing using docker

Tags: laravel, docker, storage

can't access images inside *`/public/storage`* 
i have done `php artisan storage:link`

the files are visible when using my local environment but when switching to Docker environment with the same code, i can't access them **(not found)**
**my files owner is the same as in my docker config**

i test it by visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/test.png

where test.png is inside *`public/storage`*

I have 3 services inside my docker-compose file

1. Nginx
2. PHP
3. MYSQL

I think the problem from permissions but i can't figure out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone faced the same issue.
i managed to solve this by removing the symlink created by laravel and make my own one from my nginx container based on the real path inside my container

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, each docker has an IP address. So, you have to start the server with the IP address of docker container. However, to avoid errors from docker's dynamic IP address, you use `0.0.0.0` instead of the IP address of docker because `0.0.0.0` means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. To resolve your issue, you use the following command in docker.

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

**Note**:

---

Maybe you will get another error, let me know if you meet them.

Comment: thank you for your reply, my problem isn't with the IP address, every thing is working but the storage of Laravel. i think the problem is with permissions but i can't figure what is happening. i have 3 service (nginx server, MySQL, php:fpm) inside my docker-compose file